# Express session always creating new session when making get/post request from react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express-session

I'm making post or get request from react JS using Fetch api when requesting the session from the express-session always creating new session.

Backend

```
app.use(session({
secret: 'sec12',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: keys.mongodb.dbURI,
    autoRemove: 'native',
    ttl: 9 * 60 * 60,
    mongoOptions: {
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }
  })
}));
```

cors

```
var corsOptions = {
origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
credentials:true,
preflightContinue: true,
allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'X-Requested-With', 'Accept']
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

and from the react JS

```
var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    redirect: 'follow',
    credentials: 'include',
  };
   fetch(url, requestOptions)
       .then(response => {
         if(response.ok){
            return response.json()
         }else{
            return reject('Oppps... Something went wrong the backend server not found!')
         }
       })
       .then(result => result?.error ? resolve(result) : resolve(result))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think, I figure it out.. just adding req.cookie once authenticated and parse it in every request.

put this script once the login is authenticated

```
res.cookie('access_token', token, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
```

and then using cookieParser and parse this in every request

```
 const cookieExtractor = req =>{
 let token = null;
 if(req && req.cookies){
    token = req.cookies['access_token']
  }
 return token;
 }

 // MIDDLEWARE
 passport.use(new JwtStrategy({jwtFromRequest : cookieExtractor, secretOrKey : 
   "secret01"},  async (payload, done)=>{
  User.findById({_id : payload.sub},(err, user)=>{
    if(err) {
        return done(err,false);
    }
    if(user){
        return done(null,user);
    }else{
        return done(null,false);
    }
});
}));
```